# Transcendental functions with two prescribed values

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, transcendental-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two algebraic numbers lying in unit ball. Let $T:=(t_k)_k$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers such that $t_{k+1}/t_k$ tends to $1$ as $k\to \infty$.

I would like to construct a transcendental function $f(z)=\sum_{n\in T}a_{n}z^{n}$ with integer coefficients such that $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=0$.

My main concern is convergence, because when I am trying to force $f(\alpha)=0$, the choice of coefficients in some sense destroy the possibility of $f(\beta)=0$ unless I construct a non-convergent series (which is of no interest).

Any suggestion? Even for $T$ being a known sequence, like the sequence of prime numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*
Suppose $T$ is such that there exists infinite sets $T_1, T_2 \subseteq \mathbb N$ with $T_1+T_2 \subseteq T$.

Given $\alpha,\beta$, we can try to find $f_1(z) = \sum_{n \in T_1} b_n z^n$ that vanishes at $z=\alpha_1$ and $f_2(z) = \sum_{n \in T_2} c_n z^n$ that vanishes at $\beta$.  Then $f_1(z)f_2(z)$ vanishes at both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and has the form $\sum_{n \in T} a_n z^n$.

So: can we solve the (simpler) problem where our series is required only to vanish at one given irrational?

Of course, many sets $T$ do not admit such $T_1, T_2$.

Comment: Yes, I already have used this. In fact, one always have this sumset into $T$, if the density of $T$ is positive, for example. (Joel Moreira et al proof of Erdos A+B conjecture).

Comment: Maybe it would be best, Jean, if you would lay all your cards on the table by editing into your question all the answers you already know. That way we won't bore you (and waste our own time) by posting constructions you already know about.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x),h(x)$ be any integer-coefficient polynomials vanishing at $\alpha,\beta$, respectively, and let $f(z)=g(z)h(z)(\theta(z)+(1-z)^{-1})$, where $\theta(z)=\sum_0^{\infty}z^{n^2}$ is a theta-function, known to be transcendental.

[In a previous version of this answer, I had $\log(1-z)$ playing the role of the transcendental function, but I forgot that the question required the coefficients to be integers.]

Comment: As I read the question: we are given the set $T$ of allowed powers, then we are to find a series with only those terms.

Comment: @Gerald, you're probably right. Perhaps OP will clarify.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Exactly, the only powers which can appear in the exponent of taylor series must belong to $T$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The exponents in Taylor series must belong to $T$. That is the problem

Comment: So Gerry solved the case $T = \mathbb N$.

Comment: "Any suggestion? Even for $T$ being a known sequence, like the sequence of prime numbers?" I think $1,2,3,4,\dotsc$ qualifies as a known sequence.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For positive integers is quite obvious. Actually I know how to construct for even subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with positive density.

Comment: I can't read your mind, Jean. There is nothing in the statement of your question to indicate that you know a construction for positive integers – quite the opposite, as indicated by your use of the phrase, "Even for $T$ being a known sequence". As for subsets with positive density, that can be achieved by replacing $(1-x)^{-1}$ in my answer with $(1-x^k)^{-1}$ where $k$ is larger than the degree of $g(x)h(x)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right @GerryMyerson. Sorry for the misunderstood. Actually I would like the result for general sequences $T$, but any construction for "small" sequences, like prime numbers, may provide some idea for the general case.